# Properly way to mock instance method of class

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I would like to know how to properly mock an instance method of a class.

Let's say I have two classes:

```
class A {
  doSomething() {
   /* do something here. */
  }
}

class B extends A {
  doSomethingElse() {
    this.doSomething() // calls doSomething
  }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to write unit tests to `B#doSomethingElse`, and I don't really want to call `A#doSomething`, so I need to mock that instance method. Is it possible? I came up with the following:

```
import B from './b'

let called = true

jest.mock('./a', () => {
  class A {
    public doSomething() {
      called = true;
    }
  }

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    A
  };
});

describe('B',  () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    called = false
  });

  describe('doSomethingElse', () => {
    const b = new B()
    b.doSomethingElse()

    expect(called).toEqual(true)
  });
});
```

As you can see, I'm testing if `B#doSomethingElse` is properly calling `A#doSomething`. This in fact works, but it relies on a "global" variable (`called`) which kinda bothers me. Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to make a stub for `doSomething` method.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
export class A {
  doSomething() {
    console.log('real implementation');
  }
}

export class B extends A {
  doSomethingElse() {
    this.doSomething();
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { B } from './';

describe('60853078', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const doSomethingStub = jest.spyOn(B.prototype, 'doSomething').mockReturnValueOnce();
    const b = new B();
    b.doSomethingElse();
    expect(doSomethingStub).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    doSomethingStub.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60853078/index.test.ts (10.383s)
  60853078
    ✓ should pass (11ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   90.91 |      100 |      75 |    87.5 |                   
 index.ts |   90.91 |      100 |      75 |    87.5 | 3                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.658s
```